# How to load sqlite extension in PDO?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

First, I want to inform about the case to avoid the misunderstanding.

By sqlite extension, I mention Sqlite's extension like FTS, not PHP's sqlite extension.

I have been using PDO Sqlite in my application, it cannot be changed.

As I saw [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LoadableExtensions), Sqlite extensions can be loaded as query seen below:

```
SELECT load_extension('xyz.so');
$db = new PDO ( 'sqlite:qwert.db' );
$db->query("SELECT load_extension('myextension.so');");
$db->query("SELECT myfunction(name) FROM table");
$rows = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass');
```

*Note: myfunction is method of myextension*

But when I test with this query from PDO, it return "**not authorized**" message.

For only testing purpose, I tried [PHP's Sqlite3 extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.loadextension.php) to load the extension by using the code below:

```
$db = new SQLite3('qwer.db');
$db->loadExtension('xyz.so');
```

It works

As I know that PDO Sqlite hasnot a method like loadExtension for loading extensions

Any idea how can I handle this?

Comment: You should add your code how you connect to the sqlite database and that shows how you fire the `SELECT load` query.

Comment: Where does the error occur? When loading the extension or when calling `myfunction` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

could not find a compiler flag and we have solved it with a quick'n dirty hack in pdo_sqlite extension.  patched sqlite_driver.c with sqlite3_enable_load_extension() from sqlite3 API.

```
--- php-5.3.7.old/ext/pdo_sqlite/sqlite_driver.c    2012-01-06 11:04:44.000000000 -0500
+++ sqlite_driver.c 2012-01-06 08:16:58.000000000 -0500
@@ -718,6 +718,8 @@
        goto cleanup;
    }
 
+   sqlite3_enable_load_extension(H->db, 1);
+
    if (PG(safe_mode) || (PG(open_basedir) && *PG(open_basedir))) {
        sqlite3_set_authorizer(H->db, authorizer, NULL);
    }
```

Comment: It's again fixed same issue after 7 years, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented [a library](https://github.com/Moxio/sqlite-extended-api#loading-sqlite-extensions) with a solution for this problem for PHP 7.4+ which does not involve recompiling the PDO driver. In short, it uses PHP's FFI extension and Z-Engine (which reads PHP's internal memory structures using FFI) to make a direct call to the SQLite C API. You can find more detailed background information in [this blog post](https://www.moxio.com/blog/47/how-to-load-an-sqlite-extension-in-pdo). I would not recommend this solution in production yet, but it could be a feasible workaround for test or development workflows.

Answer (score 2):

As @yagmur has answered to this question, there is the workaround with the compilation of the pdo_sqlite extension. For those who don't know how to make this, like myself days ago, the process is pretty simple (I will assume a Linux environment because I don't have experience compiling those things in Windows):

1. Make a clone of the [PHP source repository](https://github.com/php/php-src)
2. Access the branch of the PHP version you want to use, e.g. PHP-8.2 (you can access the branch with `git checkout -b PHP-8.2.9 origin/PHP-8.2.9`)
3. In the folder `ext/pdo_sqlite`, add the line `sqlite3_enable_load_extension(H->db, 1);` above the part which call the `sqlite3_set_authorizer` function on the `sqlite_driver.c` file (the function probably is called only once), as @yagmur has told to do
4. Compile the extension (below I will explain the steps to compile)
5. Copy the new compiled extension, the `pdo_sqlite.so` file generated, to the folder of your preference
6. Configure your `php.ini` file to match the pdo_sqlite path with the new one
7. Restart your PHP server
8. Test loading one extension

To compile the extension, you only need to access the folder `ext/pdo_sqlite` in the terminal and execute the following commands:

```bash
phpize
./configure
make
```

The extension probably will be on `ext/pdo_sqlite/modules` folder.

To configure the `php.ini`, you can use the cli command `php --ini`, find the path and edit the configuration. Probably will have this line in the `php.ini` file: `extension=pdo_sqlite`, but also can be in a specific file to `pdo_sqlite` configuration. Change the value to the path of your compiled extension.

If you want to test if it is working properly, you could try something like this, in this example loading the SpatiaLite extension:

```php
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:db/test.sqlite3');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, area POLYGON)";
$pdo->exec($query);

$query = "SELECT load_extension('/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite')";
try{
    $pdo->exec($query);

    $geom = "POLYGON((-3.692895967970722 40.589246298614356,-3.489648897658222 40.687204044606595,-3.357812960158222 40.50367643938022,-3.585779268751972 40.413815011684214,-3.692895967970722 40.589246298614356))";
    $query = "INSERT INTO test (area) VALUES (ST_geomFromText('$geom'))";
    $rs = $pdo->exec($query);

    $query = "SELECT ST_asText(area), ST_area(area) from test";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($statement->fetchAll(), true);
    echo "</pre>";
}catch(Throwable $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
```

But just print the SpatiaLite version with `SELECT spatialite_version()` is a quickest test too.

P.S.: I have to be honest, I don't know if this is valid for every version of the sqlite_pdo or the impacts that the version of the PHP branch has on the pdo_sqlite extension, if you can use the extension of a greater or lower version and it will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

No way present now except workaround mentioned above. If you would want to check progress somewhere in the future, there's [an issue on PHP bugtracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64810).