# Load an sqlite extension with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sqlite, doctrine

I am trying to load an `Sqlite3` extension in a `Doctrine 2` project (specifically, the `pcre` extension that I have installed via the debian package `sqlite3-pcre`).

In a plain PHP project, I would do something similar to

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$db->loadExtension('pcre.so');
```

(as per http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.loadextension.php).

*My issue is that I do not know where to tell Doctrine to call `loadExtension`, or any other way to load that extension.*

---

Side notes :

- The project is a `Symfony 4` project. The reason I use `Sqlite3` is for my functional tests (the dev and prod environments use `Postgresql`).
- I have implemented two Doctrine Extensions similar to what is done in the (semi-official ?) `DoctrineExtensions` project (e.g., the one at https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/Regexp.php):

  - One for `Postgresql` using the `~` operator. This one works perfectly.
  - One for `Sqlite3` using the `REGEXP` operator from the `pcre` extension. This one complains that `REGEXP` is undefined, since I have not managed to load the `pcre` extension.

I'd be thankful to hear any idea about how to tackle the issue.

Comment: Surely its not a valid test if you are not using all that same tools in the test

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is not uncommon in the Symfony universe to have functional tests that run on a test database, depending on what you're testing. Consider them to be in-between unit and functional tests (and you can of course have "real-world" tests as well on a prod-like database). The bundle we're using for our tests is https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle, and follows that philosophy. It advises using an in-memory sqlite3 database for speed, which is what we're doing. The Postgres Doctrine Extension for regexps that is not used in these functional tests is unit-tested separately.

Comment: @NicolasB Have you had any luck finding a solution since you posted this question? I run into the problem of wanting to test a REGEXP query on a sqlite database.

Comment: @Boschman Unfortunately no. Two possible solutions are given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756146/how-to-load-sqlite-extension-in-pdo but they were a bit overkill for our problem, so we chose to gave up on this.

Comment: @NicolasB Thanks! I'm working on a solution without sqlite in the test environment now.